# Calendar Keep Selected Date After Passing PHP Variable

Tags: javascript, php

I use the calendar code below with a minor modification I made, anyway when I select a date, the calendar highlights the date selected which is great however when I pass this selected date and redirect url, the calendar looses that selected date and it is no longer highlighted on the next page, since I am already passing the variable, how can I edit the calendar code and pass it back the selected variable so that the selected date is known and highlighted on the calendar in next page (same calendar).

```
        g_globalObject = new JsDatePick({
        useMode:1,
        isStripped:true,
        target:"div3_example"
    });     

    g_globalObject.setOnSelectedDelegate(function(){
        var obj = g_globalObject.getSelectedDay();

        if (obj.month.toString().length < 2) {
            var date = obj.year + "-0" + obj.month + "-" + obj.day
            //alert(date);
            window.top.location.href = '..index.php?pDate=' + date;
        }else
        {
            var date = obj.year + "-" + obj.month + "-" + obj.day
            //alert(date);
            window.top.location.href = '..index.php?pDate=' + date;
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

[jsDatePick](http://javascriptcalendar.org/javascript-date-picker.php) has a configuration option called `selectedDate` that can be used to pre-select a date. We can parse the query string and feed that option at initialization.

Sadly, it turns out `selectedDate` is buggy and will disable the date picker completely when used. There is a fix in [15437091/jsdatepick-using-a-selected-date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16571160/3512867) in the answer of user [Cesar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2386880/cesar) referencing [selectedDate - Problem im jsDatePick JavaScript - Modul (javascriptcalendar.org)](http://www.viathinksoft.de/?page=news&id=184) (in german) that requires a modification of the source. But rather than do that, we can use some wrapping:

```
// duplicate original function
JsDatePick.prototype.setConfiguration_original = JsDatePick.prototype.setConfiguration;

// redefine function
JsDatePick.prototype.setConfiguration = function() {

    // call original function
    JsDatePick.prototype.setConfiguration_original.apply(this, arguments);

    // use "selectedDate"
    if(this.oConfiguration.selectedDate){
        this.currentYear          = this.oCurrentDay.year;
        this.currentMonth         = this.oCurrentDay.month;
        this.currentDay           = this.oCurrentDay.day;
        this.selectedDayObject    = this.oConfiguration.selectedDate;
        this.flag_aDayWasSelected = true;
    }
}

// parse query string for selected date
var pDate = location.search.match(/[\?&]pDate=(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)/);
pDate = pDate
    ? {year:parseInt(pDate[1]), month:parseInt(pDate[2]), day:parseInt(pDate[3])}
    : null;

var g_globalObject = new JsDatePick({
    useMode:1,
    isStripped:true,
    selectedDate: pDate,
    target:"div3_example",
});
```