# How to display year selection control with jsDatePick

Tags: javascript, html, jsdatepick

Working with the jsDatePick control, I want to display **year selector controls** like [this example](http://www.mun-trofa.pt/susProjects/susGlobal/javaScript/thirdParty/jsdatepick-calendar/example-jquery.html) with the year selector controls visible `>>`:

[image]

But I can only get it to display with the **month selector** controls only:

[image]

My control is declared as such:

```
<div id="datepickerDOBWrapper" ><input type="text" id="datepickerDOB"></div>
```

and initialized with a closure:

```
$(function() {
     $("#datepickerDOB").datepicker();
});
```

I cannot find documentation that has the display options.  This [documentation](https://github.com/itamararjuan/jsdatepick) does not help.  Nor does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437091/jsdatepick-using-a-selected-date) that shows many options.

Comment: where did you find the example from the first image (with the year controls)?

Comment: @AndrewLohr - I added the source to the post.

Comment: This is what happens when you skip the coffee ;p, initializing plugin A reading the docs of plugin B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure where you got `$("#datepickerDOB").datepicker();` because it doesn't seem like that library uses that initialization.

Using the code from the [jsDatePick repo](https://github.com/itamararjuan/jsdatepick) you linked, the years come by default. Here is an example of how you should be initializing it:

Also there is really no CDN for this script, I would suggest downloading it and including it in your project. Or use a more supported date picker.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var calendar = new JsDatePick({
    useMode: 2,
    target: "datepickerDOBWrapper",
    dateFormat: "%d-%M-%Y"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/itamararjuan/jsdatepick/master/dist/jsDatePick_ltr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://rawgit.com/itamararjuan/jsdatepick/master/dist/jsDatePick.jquery.min.1.3.js"></script>

<div id="datepickerDOBWrapper"><input type="text" id="datepickerDOB"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.input-group.date').datepicker({format: "dd.mm.yyyy"});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <br />
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div id="filterDate2">
          
          <!-- Datepicker as text field -->         
          <div class="input-group date" data-date-format="dd.mm.yyyy">
            <input  type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="dd.mm.yyyy">
            <div class="input-group-addon" >
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
          
        </div>    
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

it will not run perfectly until you make new file called index.js and place this code in it

```
$('.input-group.date').datepicker({format: "dd.mm.yyyy"}); 

import jquery library
```